# php scripts becomming defunct

Tags: command-line-interface

I have a problem on a page "php scripts continues to become defunct", and appears to be the page1.php script. Parent process is terminated while child is not being terminate. I am using `shell_exec` function to run linux commands.
`shell_exec("killall -9 httpd");

shell_exec("killall -9 mysqld");

shell_exec("service httpd restart");

shell_exec("service mysqld restart");`

is this code right? 2-3K people use this file at a time. Please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

For killall and service to work the php-script need to execute as root, or some other user with appropriate permissions. Is this a standard alone shell script or a web page?

*A kill -9 should be avoided because the application may lose data, for example, mysql may not have time to save everything to permanent storage before the process is killed. Kill -9 is a convenient command for these special cases but I do not recommend to use this as a part of a script.*

Comment: may you suggest any other efficient way to kill child processes. we have 60k daily users and we are in trouble.

Comment: Can you clarify your question, I'm not completely sure what you want to do.